# Getting the corresponding x-axis value from the max value in y-axis in Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I was able to get the max value of the y-axis by this code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
var dataMax = chart.yAxis[0].dataMax;
$('#max_rainfall').html("Maximum Rainfall Intensity: <strong>"+dataMax+" mm/hr</strong>")
```

Now, how do I get the corresponding x-axis from the max y-axis value?
[image]
Example on the image, I want to get the **"2015-07-02 15:15"** because the max value on the y-axis is **37.6 mm/hr**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each series contains arrays with data points:

- `series[index].xData`
- `series[index].yData`

Since you know max value, then loop over all series and find series with highest value and get index on that `y`:

```
    var chart = $("#container").highcharts(),
        sLen = chart.series.length,
        max = chart.yAxis[0].dataMax,
        series,
        index,
        i = 0;

    for(; i < sLen; i++) {
        s = chart.series[i];
        index = s.yData.indexOf(max);
        if (index >= 0) {
            series = s;
            break;
        }
    };

    $("#report").html("x: " + s.xData[index] + ", y: " + s.yData[index] );
```

Now you have `series` and `index`, so simple get corresponding x-value:

```
var myX = series.xData[index];
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/v9582phy/5/

Comment: Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yData' of undefined

Comment: Again.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.

Comment: That's one of the reasons why I don't like jQuery, unintuitive `$.each`, try now  ;)

Comment: No error, but it results to undefined. It did not get the x-axis value. And also break statement is illegal.

Comment: Interesting, please try solution above, without jQuery ;)

Comment: It seemed to work but it gets the index of x-axis not the value. Can you take a look at this link: https://762c690d6edd49afc98bfce149e7ad120c95aba9-www.googledrive.com/host/0B0JBx-GczUoYY3VXRXg0OVZPRHM

Comment: Because you are using categories. Simply get correct category: `chart.xAxis[0].categories[index]`, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v9582phy/6/

Comment: This is a bit late, but what if I had several max values in y-axis and I wanted to get the corresponding x-axis value of the latest max ya-xis.

Comment: In the above it looks only foe the first index. If you have several values, remove break, and store all result in some array. Then loop over that arrays to return that values.

Comment: You mean store the index values in a new array?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Store indexes with corresponding series in the array.